# Why would one use reject_if if you can use validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

Is there any reason you would use `reject_if` and do something like this?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, reject_if: proc do |attributes|
    attributes['title'].blank?
  end
end
```

Instead of using validation on the Post model?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use validation, the creation of `User` will fail if there exists a `Post` which does not have a title.

If you use `reject_if`, the creation of `User` will succeed even if some, or all, of the `Post`s don't have titles. Only those posts without titles won't be saved.